# Can't import google-cloud package in Python script

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the Google Cloud audio transcription from a python file.

EDIT: I'm working on localhost, Ubuntu, python virtual, dev environment.

I keep getting the same error. I've looked on SO and none of the solutions work for me...

```
(env) localhost: pip list
pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.0.2
setuptools 59.6.0
(env) localhost: flask run --debug
flask run --debug
 * Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/openai-quickstart-python/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/var/www/openai-quickstart-python/app.py", line 47, in <module>
    transcribe_file('audio-dara.mp3')
  File "/var/www/openai-quickstart-python/app.py", line 25, in transcribe_file
    from google.cloud import speech
ImportError: cannot import name 'speech' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

This is my app.py...

```
m enum import Enum
import time, sys
# import google.cloud.texttospeech as tts                                                                                                                                              
import simpleaudio as sa
import logging
import google.cloud

# General libs                                                                                                                                                                         
app = Flask(__name__)
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

question1 = "Tell me about the Cork Gay Project?"
question2 = "Why was the Cork Gay Project created?"


def transcribe_file(speech_file):
    # Imports the Google Cloud client library                                                                                                                                          
    from google.cloud import speech

    # Instantiates a client                                                                                                                                                            
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    # The name of the audio file to transcribe                                                                                                                                         
    gcs_uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/speech/brooklyn_bridge.raw"

    audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code="en-US",
    )

    # Detects speech in the audio file                                                                                                                                                 
    response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

    for result in response.results:
        print("Transcript: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))

transcribe_file('audio-dara.mp3')
```

I can't seem to fix this error. pip list doesn't seem to list the installed packages on a virtual environment? I know i have the google-cloud package installed but it doesn't show...

```
(env) localhost: sudo pip install google-cloud
sudo pip install google-cloud
Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (0.34.0)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

Comment: Where are  you trying to perform the pip install? On your workstation? On a Google Cloud Service?

Comment: Localhost in a python virtual environment

Comment: The `google-cloud` package was deprecated in 2018. Do not install or reference that package. Please install the product-specific google-cloud-* packages needed for your application.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley you're right. google-cloud was deprecated in 2018. It appears i was using Google's example code from STT v1 here https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/samples/speech-transcribe-async#speech_transcribe_async-python